# Force AWS account numbers that start with "00" to string

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Does anybody know a work-around for converting account numbers that start with “00” to string? I am using Mappings in CFn template to assign values based on the account number. I put the account number in quotes for converting it to string and it works well if it does not start with a zero, and I get the following error when it does.:

> [/Mappings/EnvMap] map keys must be strings; received numeric [1.50xxx028E9]

```yaml
Mappings:
  EnvMap:
    "8727xxxx0": 
      env: "dev"
    "707xxxx78":
      env: "test"
    "00150xxx280":
      env: "prod"


Resources:
  rS3Stack:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack"
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/some_bucket/nested_cfn/s3.yaml"
      Parameters:
        pEnvironment: !FindInMap
          - EnvMap
          - !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
          - env
```

Comment: have you tried using single quotes?

Comment: yes, it doesnt detect it. Getting the error " Unable to get mapping for EnvMap::001xxxx80::env"

Comment: in your sample, I think you're missing a colon after id  "00150xxx280"

Comment: It doesn't work even with the colon.

Comment: How do you deploy this template with CloudFormation? Do you use something like the `aws-sam-cli` or `aws cloudformation package`? Do you deploy it manually using the management console?

Comment: I should have looked at the [list of supported functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-findinmap.html#w2ab1c25c28c26c13) before answering. The only functions allowed in a `FindInMap` are `!Ref` and another `!FindInMap`. Answer deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused by a [bug in PyYAML](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/issues/98) which results from some ambiguity in the YAML 1.1 specification. According to YAML 1.1 an integer must not start with `0` and numbers starting with `0` and are considered octal numbers. So when PyYAML parses the account id it considers the account id not to be an integer, because it's starting with `0`, but also not an octal number, because it contains an `8`. As it's neither an integer, nor an octal number, PyYAML considers it a string, which is safe to get dumped without surrounding quotes.

A minimal example to reproduce this looks like this:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.dump(["1", "8", "01", "08"], sys.stdout)
- '1'
- '8'
- '01'
- 08
```

Now you might wonder why a PyYAML bug is mentioned here, while you just want to deploy a CloudFormation stack:

Depending on how you deploy a CloudFormation stack the template might get transformed locally, before it gets deployed. That happens for example when using `aws cloudformation package`, `sam package` or `sam build` to replace local code locations with paths in S3. As reading and writing the template during those transformations is done using PyYAML, it triggers the PyYAML bug mentioned above. There are bug reports for the [AWS CLI](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2934) and the [AWS SAM CLI](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/200) regarding this problem.

As the account id causing the problem is used as a key in your case, your options to work around that problem are limited, as you can't utilize CloudFormation's intrinstic functions. However there are still possible workarounds:

If you're using the AWS CLI, you can switch to using the AWS CLI v2, which doesn't suffer from this bug as it uses `ruamel` instead of `PyYAML`. `ruamel` handles numbers as one would expect, as it implements YAML 1.2, which doesn't contain the ambiguity in its specification.

What you can use no matter if you're using the AWS SAM CLI or the AWS CLI is to convert the transformed template from YAML to JSON and back to YAML which "fixes" that bug as well, as it results in problematic numbers being quoted again. There is a tool called [`cfn-flip`](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cfn-template-flip) from AWS to do so. You'd have to run this double-flip between packaging and deployment. For the AWS SAM CLI that'd for example look like:

```
sam build
cfn-flip .aws-sam/build/template.yaml | cfn-flip > .aws-sam/build/template.tmp.yaml
mv .aws-sam/build/template.tmp.yaml .aws-sam/build/template.yaml
sam deploy
```

With this said, I personally would suggest a completely different workaround and that's to remove that mapping from the template. Hardcoding account ids and environments makes a template less portable, as it limits the accounts/environments this template can be used for. I'd instead provide the environment as a parameter to the CloudFormation template, so it doesn't need to be aware of account ids at all.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went with a different work-around for this issue. Since I am using codepipeline for the deployment, I am using parameter-overrides to force the value of Env. in my deploy stage.
     ParameterOverrides: >
          {
              "pEnvironment": "stage"
          }